# js air-datepicker input and required doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

I use `air-datepicker` input but required attribute doesn't work

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/css/datepicker.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/js/datepicker.min.js"></script>



<form>
<input type="text" class="datepicker-here" id="dob" required readonly ></input>

<button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Create [mre] using snippet, code you posted is not showing us anything...

Comment: its ok now . i need the input to be required and readonly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To not go too much into why is this happening as I do not use that datepicker, why you simply do not create your own required check with JS? I see read-only is working...

```js
document.getElementById("myform").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  if (document.getElementById("dob").value === "") {
    window.alert("Date empty!");
    // Create here what you wish, tooltip, alert, css styling, html alert...
  } else {
    document.getElementById("myform").submit();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/css/datepicker.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/js/datepicker.min.js"></script>



<form id="myform">
  <input type="text" class="datepicker-here" id="dob" required readonly>

  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```